# C++ Separate string from line in text file

Tags: c++, string, file, fstream, substring

I am having trouble separating a particular string from a line of text in a file that I've "uploaded" in C++.

Below is the line that I'd like to parse by column.

2016/12/6 s "The incestuous relationship between government and big business thrives in the dark. ~Jack Anderson [4]" 0 3 39 blue white PATRICK BARDWELL

I need each piece of information in a different variable, and at first I was implementing inFile >> var1 >> var2 >> etc; but when I get to the quote, this method only takes the first word of the quote: "The " and then stops.

Any tips on how to put everything that's inside the " " into a single string? My current code is below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

// int main

int main()
{

    // Declare variables
    string userFile;
    string line;
    string date;
    char printMethod;
    string message;
    int numMedium;
    int numLarge;
    int numXL;
    string shirtColor;
    string inkColor;
    string customerName;
    string customerEmail;
    string firstLine;
    string delimiter = "\"";


    // Prompt user to 'upload' file

    cout << "Please input the name of your file:\n";
    cin >> userFile;
    fstream inFile;
    inFile.open(userFile.c_str());

    // Check if file open successful -- if so, process

    if (inFile.is_open())
    {
        getline(inFile, firstLine); // get column headings out of the way
        cout << firstLine << endl << endl;

        while(inFile.good()) // while we are not at the end of the file, process
        {
            getline(inFile, line);
            inFile >> date >> printMethod;

        }

        inFile.close();
    }

    // If file open failure, output error message, exit with return 0;

    else
    {

        cout << "Error opening file";

    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Read the entire string into a variable, and _then_ do the parsing. Have you experimented with [regex](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/)?

Comment: How do I parse after reading everything into a variable? And no I haven't, first I'm hearing about it (brand new C++ student). Thanks for responding btw.

Comment: Open your C++ book to the chapter that describes `std::string`. You must've started reading this chapter, since you're using `std::string`s in your code. Well, the very same chapter also describes many amazing methods that the `std::string` class has. Like `find()`, to find a character in the string, and `substr()`, to take pieces of the string out. What else do you need? Use `find()` to find where the various parts of the string are, and `substr()` to extract them. Problem solved. Learning how to read technical documentation is a required skill for every C++ developer.

Comment: Sam Varshavchik -- thank you! I've got it now :) you guys have been a big help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`regex`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/) module to parse the quoted text from the string after you've read it into a variable. Be sure to `#include <regex>`.

In your case, you're reading each line into a variable called `line`. We can pass the variable `line` to a function called [`regex_search`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_search/) which will extract the quoted text match and put it into another variable, in this case `res`. `res[1]` holds the match that we're interested in, so we assign it to a variable called `quotedText`.

```
string quotedText;
while(inFile.good()) // while we are not at the end of the file, process
{
    getline(inFile, line);

    regex exp(".*\"(.*)\"");          // create a regex that will extract quoted text
    smatch res;                       // will hold the search information
    regex_search(line, res, exp);     // performs the regex search
    quotedText = res[1];              // we grab the match that we're interested in- the quoted text
    cout << "match: " << quotedText << "\n";
    cout << "line: " << line << "\n";
}
```

You're then free to do whatever you'd like with `quotedText`.

Regex syntax is a whole topic of itself. For more information, [see the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae5bf541(v=vs.100).aspx).